# Inconsistent hum from front driver

Tags: vibration, lexus, shaking

Inconsistent hum from front driver side and little shaky especially after 80mph. On a 2014 Lexus GS350 sounds like tire and did not see anything wrong with the tire

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You may have lost a balancing weight - they do come off sometimes.

Comment: What's inconsistent about the hum? Does it get higher or louder the faster you go, or does it come and go at any speed?

Comment: I have an inconsistent whistle from my front driver.  Its my wife. Drives me crazy. She has to whistle with every song on the radio.

Comment: "*Inconsistent hum from front driver*" I hate it when the driver hums inconsistently,  For the love of Pete, Take some humming lessons .

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to comment but are you're sure the tires are properly balanced and theres nothing wrong with the rims? Tires can be worn on the outside part of the wheel facing the car, you'd have to get down and properly check. But getting the front wheels balanced would be a cheap and easy first check.

If its a wavy vibration hum like sound it could possibly be the wheel bearing, thats what they usually sound like. The faster you go the louder the hum. Some more unlikely things would be warped break rotor or bent caliper.

This car is rear wheel drive right? Answer above assumes rwd.